# malloc error while finding the second maximum element in an array

Tags: c++

I encountered a specific malloc error while trying to find the second most maximum element in an array. This error did not pop while finding my element in an array which I created statically , so may be possible that I have made an error while dynamically creating the array. Can someone look into this and guide me please

C++ code ->

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
//Function to calculate second maximum
int second_max(int arr[],int size){
  int largest=INT_MIN;
  int second_largest = INT_MIN;

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    // If current element is greater than the maximum , we reassign
    // the maximum and second maximum value 
    if(arr[i]>largest){
      second_largest = largest;
      largest = arr[i];
    }
     // If current element is in between maximum & second maximum
     // we update second maximum
    else if(second_largest<arr[i] && arr[i]<largest){
      second_largest=arr[i];
    }
  }
  if(second_largest==INT_MIN){
    // Return -1 is second maximum not found
    return -1; 
  }
  else{
    return second_largest;
  }
}
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int size;
  cin>>size;
  // dynamically defined array
  int *arr=new int(size); 
  // Taking inputs
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    cin>>arr[i]; 
  }
  cout<<second_max(arr,size);
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What size are you inserting for your `arr`?

Comment: `int *arr=new int(size);` allocates a single `int` with a value of `size`. You want `int *arr=new int[size];` instead. Since you're using C++ you might consider `std::vector<int>` instead and use the `push_back()` function to add items to it.

Comment: `std::vector` solves a lot of problems, especially pointer related ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said by @RetiredNinja to correct your mistake replace `new int(size)` with `new int[size]`, also don't forget to always `delete` allocated pointers.

As already said by others if you're using C++ then best way is to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of manual new/delete, it manages all memory allocations automatically and saves you from mistakes.

Below is your working code with minmal changes with migrations to std::vector:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/n3Mqa58P7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

//Function to calculate second maximum
int second_max(int arr[],int size){
  int largest=INT_MIN;
  int second_largest = INT_MIN;

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    // If current element is greater than the maximum , we reassign
    // the maximum and second maximum value 
    if(arr[i]>largest){
      second_largest = largest;
      largest = arr[i];
    }
     // If current element is in between maximum & second maximum
     // we update second maximum
    else if(second_largest<arr[i] && arr[i]<largest){
      second_largest=arr[i];
    }
  }
  if(second_largest==INT_MIN){
    // Return -1 is second maximum not found
    return -1; 
  }
  else{
    return second_largest;
  }
}
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int size;
  cin>>size;
  // dynamically defined array
  std::vector<int> arr(size); 
  // Taking inputs
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    cin>>arr[i]; 
  }
  cout<<second_max(arr.data(),size);
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5
1 4 3 2 5
```

Output:

```
4
```